# Application Insights: Calculate Max RPS for API- Request

Tags: azure-application-insights, azure-api-management

I want to form a KQL query to determine max RPS for particular API Request over a given time.
For eg: To determine max RPS over a duration of 2 months for particular API in App Insights.
I am able to determine Average RPS, but that would only work for relatively shorter durations (in seconds).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using the `requests` table in Application Insights, here's how you can construct the query:

1. Filter the data by the API endpoint or path you're interested in.
2. Bin the data by one-second intervals.
3. Count the number of requests in each bin.
4. Return the maximum count.

```
requests
| where timestamp > ago(2m)  // Filter to consider the last 2 months.
| where url contains "/your-api-endpoint-path"  // Modify this with your specific API endpoint or path.
| summarize CountPerSecond = count() by bin(timestamp, 1s)
| order by CountPerSecond desc
| take 1
```